# Клиент-серверная технология для создания мессенджера

Tags: android, клиент-сервер

Хочу создать некое приложение, где люди могут посылать друг другу картинки с сообщениями. Раньше пользовался только схемой: "клиент запросил - сервер ответил". Но здесь нужно, чтобы сервер сам посылал сообщения. Как вообще такое делается? Сокеты? Push-уведомления?

Comment: Сокеты, Push-уведомления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сокеты.
2. Пуши.
3. Long polling механизм. Посылается post-запрос. Сервер не сразу отвечает, а лишь когда появятся новые сообщения. Если за 20 сек. не ответил, то шлём по-новой и т.д. Хотя, я этот механизм для чата, как правило, использовал. Но и для месенджера подойдёт.

Comment: В моем случае, сообщения будут отправляться не сильно часто и не сильно много. Предполагаю, здесь стоит использовать пуши?

Comment: @azat, ну да, неплохой вариант, в принципе. Вот только если не слишком часто, то можно же тогда обычными post-запросами с клиента обойтись на получение обновлений.